# Mysql update caused entire table to be updated with same value

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I need assistance trying to find a problem where 1 record/row was updated but the entire table got updated with the same value.  Need to understand how this could have happened and implement a method to prevent it from doing so again.

`update TABLE set pushID='1234567890' where userID='111222333'` ;

What would that update statement do if the userID value equaled nothing or equaled NULL?  Could that cause the update statement to update every single row with the same pushID?

IE: `update TABLE set pushID='1234567890' where userID=''` ;

Could a blank userID value cause this?  If not, what could cause this?  If so, how could I write the query statement to prevent this from happening again?

Answer (score 0):

In case these are altogether integer ID, you should not convert them to string with `''`. Doing so may lead to unexpected results (never tried, but it seems to be a possible cause for the comparison in the `WHERE` condition to fail). For example:

```
UPDATE TABLE SET pushID=1234567890 WHERE userID=111222333;
```

When all records are being updated, the query lacks the `WHERE` condition. Make sure to have posted the correct query, because this query should update nothing when the `WHERE` condition fails to match.

Answer (score 0):

> What would that update statement do if the `userID` value equaled nothing or equaled NULL?

If the `userID` is `NULL`, then the condition becomes `userID = NULL`. This will always evaluate as false. In other words, no record will be updated.

If the `userID` is the empty string, then the condition becomes `userID = ''`. This will only update records where `userID` is equal to the empty string. I would expect that `userID` is the primary key of your table, so it would be suprising the find an empty value. And even if there is one, it will be unique, so a unique record will be updated.

As you see, none of the two above use case would generate a massive update of the table. The most probable option is that the query was triggered without an actual `WHERE` clause, like:

```
update TABLE set pushID='1234567890'
```